# DIY schematic for solar lamp

Tags: solar-cell

I read about this [article](http://green.thefuntimesguide.com/2008/09/cheap_solar_power_light.php) about solar lamp. Obviously I can bought the whole thing online by spending $30 something but I want to make it by myself.

I hope this is the right place to look for. I am not sure if this belong to another SE. I have no electrical experience except the little thing I learn from high school. With a proper instruction, I think I can build it by myself from the scratch.

I googled around for "DIY solar lamp" but I cannot find any page which am not using already made $1 solar road lamp, however, I want to bought the things including solar cell, diode, etc and assemble them by myself.

I found this [article](http://noelbautista.com/blog/diy-solar-lantern-part-13/) which seems to be teaching it but it is lacking the 
graph.

I've attached an schematic below which I found on the internet. It is about a solar lamp with  a solar cell of size 25x18x5 cm, which I don't think could fit in a jar. I place it here for a reference. It is from Taiwan so it is Chinese. I've made a translation for you.

What I need is a instruction to build a solar lamp from scratch and it could fit in a small jar. Do you have any idea?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look for "solar lamp schematic", it will give you many schematics for making one yourself on google.

Here is one [image: Solar lamp schematic] from http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/SolarLight/SolarLight.html which explains how and why it works, as well as having some variations on it.

The reason most people just use a dollar store solar light is because it's insanely cheaper then getting the parts yourself. Just buying the solar panel itself will cost you 5 bucks at radioshack, or a few bucks on ebay plus shipping time. Then you need the rechargeable battery, and the inductors. It's not very cost effective at this point.

But in essence, you only need a few parts. The solar cell which charges the battery during the day, the battery which runs the led at night, and a small control circuit to prevent the led from lighting up during the day.